# US investments for a non-resident alien

Tags: united-states, non-resident, f1-student-visa

Where am I allowed to invest my money in the US considering that I am non-resident alien (I have a F1 visa)?

I noticed that most of the brokerage or investment platforms online do not allow people with this status to open accounts. Is there any way to invest money in US?

Comment: I don't think any bank I opened an account with ever asked for my status....

Comment: Yes, you can open bank accounts with most banks. What about brokerage accounts? The ones I checked do not allow me to open an account...

Comment: Where did you notice that? I'm on F1 too and have all sorts of accounts, incl. broker accounts.

Comment: Are you Non-Resident Alien?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to open a brokerage account using an address in the country where you are resident. Many of the online brokerages accept international accounts, but they may be selective about which countries they serve. You will not likely find a broker willing to register you as an international client using a US address.

I'm not really sure how your F1 visa plays into this, however.